# My button doesn't work when I add class="col-lg-*"

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have this problem that's really annoying.

The only thing I found out is that when I erase class="col-lg-7" on my div, the button works...

IT WORKS : The button has an hover effect, and the cursor changes...

IT DOESN'T WORK : No hover effect, no cursor changes, I feel like the cursor is in the background

```
<div class="col-lg-3 divDarkBlue menu2">
    <div class="col-lg-12">

        <fieldset>
           <div class="row">

               <div class="col-lg-5">
                   <asp:Label ID="lblCourriel" runat="server" Text="Courriel"></asp:Label>
               </div>

               <!-- WHEN I ERASE THE CLASS OF THE DIV col-lg-7, THE BUTTON WORKS...-->

                <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCourriel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
          </div>
       </fieldset>

       <div class="row"> 
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary pull-right" Text="Envoyer" OnClick="btnConnexion_Click" />
      </div>

   </div> 
</div>
```

Does anybody knows why ? Or something I could continue to search ? I'm really lost right now!

```
.divDarkBlue {
background-color: darkblue;
color: white;
}
.menu2 {
color: white;
 }
```

**EDIT** Here is the jsfiddle. First time on this site. Let me know if I can improve something to help you.. http://jsfiddle.net/t5enyedv/

**EDIT** It seems like I can't post a picture because I don't have enough reputation.. well that picture would of helps. It seem like my button is only clickable OUTSIDE de col-lg-12. So it's like this column is ON the button... but why??? How can I undo that...

Comment: typo there I guess, should be col-lg-12

Comment: You are saying that my div around my TextBox should not be col-lg-7 BUT col-lg-12?!?!

Comment: <div class="col-lg12"> -> col-lg-12

Comment: THANKS! But it still doesn't works. The outcome is better now though. lol

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: turn on developer tool on your browser, compare the css attributes when you have col-lg-7 and without

Comment: Here it is. It's the first time I'm using jsfiddle. It's in ASP, so the button doesn't show up... should I post the Source code (the generated HTML) instead? http://jsfiddle.net/t5enyedv/

Comment: why you need this css `.rowContent [class*="col-"]{
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
}`

Comment: It is to make the blue columns the same height as the content column (the Lorem Ipsum). Thanks Grundy for the help tho!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try decreasing the col value of one or both of the two controls (label and textbox). They might be overflowing the row container for some reason.

Comment: I tried, it still doesn't work that way. Now i found out that it seems like the big "col-lg-12" is ON the button. But why? And How can I undo that or hacks something to make it work...

Comment: I think that is because outside of the big "col-lg-12" that you are referencing is a col-lg-3. That will limit the size of anything inside of it.

Answer (score -1):

You have two div closing tags surrounding the text box.

```html
<div class="col-lg-7">
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtMotDePasse" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" TextMode="Password"> </asp:TextBox>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is the closing tag of the <div class="row"> just before the Label.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason the JSFiddle didn't connect them so it made it appear as if it was incorrect.